# Sea launch for starship super heavy will need some kind of flame diverter. Any idea how it will work?

Tags: spacex-starship, flame, sea-launch

Animations of starship taking off from a barge or platform appear as if there is no flame diverter at all. Any idea how that will be handled, especially since they plan so much traffic? Also how has flame been handled in previous sea launches? Is there any advantage in being on water? One imagines a strategy of directing flame directly into the sea. (Probably only feasible if the platform is on legs rather than floating)

Comment: Launching directly over water could easily create steam explosions

Comment: Did you try surfing thru spacex.com to see if they discuss this?

Comment: All we have for precedence is SeaLaunch. They vented exhaust under the floating platform, and it worked well enough. “Will it scale?” is an open question. 

http://s7space.ru/en/launch-sea/